# Pasting values on excel with an vba code doesn't work: Error defined by the object application (1004)

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code to copy and paste values on a new spreadsheet:

```
Sub createSpreadSheet()

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
szToday = Format(Date - 1, "YYYYMMDD")
    With NewBook
        .Title = "Control_precios_ddmmaaaa"
        .Subject = "Control_de_precios"
        .SaveAs Filename:="V:\Departamento\7920-SOLVENCIA\1. Riesgo de Mercado\2. RIESGO DE CONTRAPARTIDA\1. REPORTING DIARIO R.Contrapartida\1. Enviados\Nuevo_Informe_CR_" & szToday & ".xls"
    End With

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
NewBook.Sheets(1).Activate
ActiveSheet.Name = "EXPOSICION"
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

When I run the code it stops at the last instruction with the 1004 error: Error defined by the object application. Its strange that the same code for another worksheet worked.

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Was the other worksheet on the same computer?

Comment: Yes, it is, I've already checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in a different way, without all the `Select`, and the **Copy>>Paste** lines one after the other:

```
Option Explicit

Sub createSpreadSheet()

Dim NewBook As Workbook
Dim szToday As String

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
szToday = Format(Date - 1, "YYYYMMDD")
With NewBook
    .Title = "Control_precios_ddmmaaaa"
    .Subject = "Control_de_precios"
    .SaveAs Filename:="V:\Departamento\7920-SOLVENCIA\1. Riesgo de Mercado\2. RIESGO DE CONTRAPARTIDA\1. REPORTING DIARIO R.Contrapartida\1. Enviados\Nuevo_Informe_CR_" & szToday & ".xls"

    .Sheets(1).Name = "EXPOSICION"
End With

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy

With NewBook.Sheets(1)
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
```

attempts to activate a workbook and select a sheet in the same line.  Split into 2 lines:

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets(1).Select
```

Comment: But the OP says he is getting the error on the last line.